# bootstrap-table localization with requirejs gives error "Cannot read property 'locales' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, typo3, requirejs, bootstrap-table

Using TYPO3 as CMS, I'm trying to load bootstrap-table localizations using requirejs but I get this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'locales' of undefined`.

First of all, if I only load [bootstrap-table.min.js](https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js) everything works:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'TYPO3/CMS/Iancalendar/bootstrap-table.min'
], function($, bootstrapTable) {
```

But I get that error when I add the localization file:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'TYPO3/CMS/Iancalendar/bootstrap-table.min',
    'TYPO3/CMS/Iancalendar/bootstrap-table-locale-all.min'
], function($, bootstrapTable, btl) {
```

The error fires at this line of [bootstrap-table-locale-all.min.js](https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.0/dist/bootstrap-table-locale-all.min.js):

```
t.fn.bootstrapTable.locales["af-ZA"]
```

So I guess that's because t.fn.bootstrapTable is not yet defined there.

Please, any idea to help me solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using addRequireJsConfiguration method of PageRenderer with this code to ext_localconf.php

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer::class)->addRequireJsConfiguration([
    'shim' => [
        'bootstrapTable' => ['jquery'],
        'bootstrapTableLocale' => ['jquery', 'bootstrapTable'],
    ],
    'paths' => [
        'bootstrapTable' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\PathUtility::getAbsoluteWebPath(
                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath('iancalendar', 'Resources/Public/JavaScript/Contrib/')
            ) . 'bootstrap-table.min',
        'bootstrapTableLocale' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\PathUtility::getAbsoluteWebPath(
                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath('iancalendar', 'Resources/Public/JavaScript/Contrib/')
            ) . 'bootstrap-table-locale-all.min',
    ]
]);
```

This way I can load the modules in Main.js like this

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'bootstrapTable',
    'bootstrapTableLocale'
], function($, bootstrapTable, bootstrapTableLocale) {
...
```